# Using map on every other list item Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Lets say I want to multiply every other integer in a list by 2.

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
double = lambda x: x * 2
print map(double, list[::2])
```

I get returned the slice of every other item.

What if I want to destructively change every other item in a list so I get returned the list `[1, 4, 3, 8]` instead?

Comment: don't use builtin keywords as variable names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can assign to a slice:

```
>>> list_ = [1,2,3,4]
>>> double = (2).__mul__
>>> map(double, list_[1::2])
[4, 8]
>>> list_[1::2] = map(double, list_[1::2])
>>> list_
[1, 4, 3, 8]
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you want to do this in a functional way? This could be much more easy to read:

```
for i in range(1, len(l), 2):
    l[i] = l[i] * 2
```

or you can use simple list comprehension and assign the slice:

```
l[1::2] = [x * 2 for x in l[1::2]]
```

Or

```
l = [x * (2 if i % 2 == 1 else 1) for i, x in enumerate(l)]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change the definition for lambda

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
double = lambda l: [l[x]*2 if x%2!=0 else l[x] for x in range(len(l))]
print lambda(lst)
```

Comment: Maybe using `enumerate(l)` instead of `range(len(l))` could be useful: you will get the index right away. The last part will be like: `for i, v in enumerate(l)` where i is the index and v is the value from the list.